# Simplyfy the mysql query for the insert

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am working on creating a new query for inserting values in to a table  which pulls values from the other table

```
 INSERT INTO user (EmailAddress, InternalPhone, ExternalPhone,  CreatedBy, DateCreated,roll_key,user_key )
 VALUES ( NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 'dba', Now(),  
 (select r.roll_key from user u
    join work wrk on u.work_key = wrk.Work_key
    join roll r on r.Name = 'Ext'
    where u.Name = 'test'),
 (select u.user_key from user u
    join work wrk on u.work_key = wrk.Work_key
    join roll r on r.Name = 'Ext'
    where u.Name = 'test'))
```

How can I simply this query instead of having the select statements in to the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single select and  assign the fixed value to pseudo column

```
  INSERT INTO user (EmailAddress, InternalPhone, ExternalPhone,  CreatedBy, DateCreated,roll_key,user_key )
  select   NULL, NULL, 1, 'dba', Now(),    r.roll_key, u.user_key
  from user u
  join work wrk on u.work_key = wrk.Work_key
  join roll r on r.Name = 'Ext'
  where u.Name = 'test'
```

Comment: I get an error saying Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 'dba', Now(),    r.roll_key, u.user_key at line 2